# ¿Que algoritmo de cifrado se puede usar para guardar datos en Java?

Tags: java, encriptación

Estoy desarrollando un programa en Java y en un punto de este quiero que cifre una palabra antes de guardarla en una base de datos. Ahora mismo me codifica con Base64 de la librería Apache commons.

¿Existe algún tipo de cifrado que me permita mantener los datos mas seguros que mi actual metodo y que también use una palabra para cifrar?
(Se que Base64 no es un tipo de cifrado como tal)

Comment: Daniel, si preguntas por una solución, trata de evitar preguntar por "lo mejor". Aparte de arriesgar de provocar una discusión casi religiosa, existe algo como una alergia a esta palabra en preguntas y usualmente te queda cerrado en poco tiempo. Prefiere de preguntar por **una** solución  dentro de un contexto.

Comment: Base64 NO es una encriptacion.

Comment: @leonbloy ayudame con mi vocabulario entonces, existe la palabra encodificación?

Comment: Los terminos son [cifrar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9Blo7Je) y [codificar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9dZx6FB)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Para empezar, `Base64` es una codificación que no apunta a proteger tus datos, porque es completamente reversible. `Base64` es nada más que otra representación de una cadena de bytes, como una cadena de hex (Base16). Sin ningún secreto puedes calcular el dato original desde una cadena de `Base64`.

Si simplemente quieres guardar la contraseña como [hash](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_hash) que evita que se puede deducir la contraseña del dato guardado, puedes usar un `java.security.MessageDigest` ([Algoritmos disponibles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest)). Ejemplo:

```
// elige por ejemplo entre los algoritmos disponibles
// en este caso un 48 byte sha-384
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-384");
byte[] digest = md.digest(passwd.getBytes("UTF-8"));
// luego puedes guardar los byte o transformarlos en otro formato como hexString etc.
```

Para eso no se usa una palabra secreta.

**Si quieres encriptar con secreto**

Puedes usar la biblioteca `javax.crypto` para encriptación con palabra clave. En este ejemplo se usa el algoritmo AES, `clave` es la palabra clave y `iv` el vector de inicialización (como semilla).

Más información sobre `AES` encuentras [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class MiCipher {

    public static SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();

    public static String encriptar(String clave, byte[] iv, String value) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(clave.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

            byte[] encriptado = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encriptado);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decriptar(String clave, byte[] iv, String encriptado) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(clave.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

            byte[] dec = cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encriptado));
            return new String(dec);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String clave = "FooBar1234567890"; // 128 bit
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        sr.nextBytes(iv);
        String encriptado = encriptar(clave, iv, "Demasiados Secretos!");
        System.out.println(String.format("encriptado: %s", encriptado));
        System.out.println(decriptar(clave, iv, encriptado));
    }
}
```

*fin de TLDR;*

***Sobre criptografía y aclaración de terminos***

**1) Que valor criptográfico tiene la codificación `Base64`?**

Ninguno. Como codificación, Base64 es una función bidireccional que representa una cadena de datos en segmentos de 6bits por los caracteres [A-Za-z0-9] más dos que dependen de la implementación.
En este caso (xsd:base64Binary) los dos caracteres demás son `+` y `/`, mientras `=` indica el fin de cadena.

La códificación aquí se usa, porque después de cifrar la cadena original recibimos un resultado como cadena de bytes que podrían contener caracteres no representables. La base 64 nos permite de incorporar los datos cifrados en documentos xml, correo o por ejemplos campos de texto en una BBDD.

**2) ¿Que puedo usar entonces para cifrar datos con secretos?**

En el ejemplo arriba mostré como se usa `AES`, un algoritmo simétrico (en contrario a por ejemplo RSA, que es asimétrico). `AES` usa cifras de 128, 192 o 256bit y esta ya en 128bit considerado muy seguro (suficientemente seguro para la NSA). Como todos los algoritmos criptográficos, siempre existe la posibilidad de decifrar los datos, pero `AES` esta generalmente considerado invulnerable a ataques menos por fuerza bruta (probando claves hasta la decriptación funciona).

**3) ¿Que es la diferencia entre algoritmos simétricos y asimétricos?**

Algoritmos simétricos (como `AES`, `DES` o `Blowfish`) usan una sola clave (un secreto) para cifrar y decifrar una cadena de datos. Así ambos partes tienen que tener la clave y en el caso que la clave esta comprometida la cifra pierde su uso.

Algoritmos asimétricos (como `RSA`) en lo contrario usan dos secretos, usualmente nombrado el secreto publico y el secreto privado. Para decifrar una cadena de datos cifrado con uno de los secretos se necesita usar el **otro** secreto.

**4) ¿Que entonces es un *hash* y para que se usa en el contexto de seguridad?**

Un [*hash*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_hash) es una función unidireccional que calcula un valor de tamaño definido desde una cadena de tamaño variable. Un *hash* es una representación abstracta de un dato en particular, y no necesariamente tiene que ser "perfecto" (significando que nunca dos datos distintos tienen el mismo *hash*).
En el almacenamiento de contraseñas en bases de datos existe la buena practica de guardarlos en forma de un *hash*, en el caso ideal más largo que la tipica contraseña. El beneficio de seguridad es solamente que en el caso que un atacante obtiene acceso a las contraseñas, se le hace difícil de adivinar la contraseña que resulta en el calculo del *hash*.

**5) Donde se aplican y como se combinan los distintos métodos**

El cifrado asimétrico es mucho más costoso en contexto de calculo que el cifrado simétrico. El problema del cifrado simétrico sin embargo es el despacho de la clave del origen al destino, porque en el caso que la clave esta descubierto por un atacante la cifra esta quebrada.

Con el cifrado asimétrico la clave publica se puede hacer públicamente accesible mientras la clave privada se mantiene fuera del alcance, eso permite que se puede iniciar una transmisión hacía la maquina desde cualquier origen que no puede ser decifrado por terceros.

Por eso se usa el cifrado asimétrico para transmitir la clave para el cifrado simétrico después, que maneja el trabajo pesado de cifrar los datos útiles que se tienen que transferir en manera segura.

Guardar contraseñas como *hash* como ya mencionado protege la contraseña de estar leído de por ejemplo bases de datos que fueron comprometidos, pero para proteger la contraseña contra ataques del "hombre entremedio" en que un atacante observa las transmisiones entre origen y destino hay que usar de nuevo un cifrado asimétrico.

**6) ¿Que es el vector de inicialisación y porque se crea en forma aleatoria?**

El vector de inicialisación se usa para evitar algunos vectores de ataque a la cifra. No se debería usar un vector de inicialisación para cifrar/decifrar dos cadenas de datos distintos, o se entregan patrones que facilitan romper la cifra. En el caso de un cifrador de bloques que trabaja por iteración sobre los bloques sirve como bloque inicial, y por eso tiene el mismo tamaño que un bloque de datos.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarme cual es la función del vector de inicialización y el por que su tamaño es 16?

Comment: @StefanNolde puedes mencionar que es un hash, que AES es criptografía simétrica y poner enlaces? Sería una respuesta excelente si solo mencionaras esas cosas :)

Comment: Si, lo haré un poco más rato probable. Mejoro mis respuestas cuando puedo. También intento de hablar un poco más de los casos de uso para distintas formas de encriptación, eso por ahora es el TLDR; ;)

Comment: He conseguido el cifrado y descifrado sin usar Secure Random (        sr.nextBytes(iv)). Si lo uso, para un mismo dato me crea cada vez una cadena distinta y no puedo descifrarla. Supongo que (sr.nextBytes(iv);) modifica aleatoriamente la clave secreta. Dicho de otro modo: Si descifro la cadena en la misma ejecución del programa desencripta bien, en la siguiente ejecución ya no puede por que el sr es distinto. ¿Qué puedo hacer para desencriptar? Tengamos en cuenta que lo encriptado lo estoy guardando en una base de datos, por lo tanto los datos encriptados ya los recojo al abrir el programa.

Comment: @DanielRuiz que te crea una cadena distinta en el ejemplo es la idéa. Un iv debería ser aleatorio y se debería usar como un dato desechable. se usa para cifrar y luego para decifrar un dato. En el enlace sobre AES sale más sobre el porque. El comentario queda corto para explicarte todo el porque, si puedes presentar más concreto que haces, se puede dar mejor consejo como manejarlo bien. En todo caso trata de entender todo lo que haces en la criptografía, o te engañas con sentirte más seguro que estas.

Comment: Tu puedes guardar el `iv`en la misma base de datos en la forma que te conviene, agregado al dato o en un blob referenciando el dato que cifraste con el, siempre mientras evitas que usas el mismo `iv` para dos datos distintos.

Comment: Ese es justo el problema. Que como el IV es aleatorio al desencriptar un dato de la base de datos en una segunda ejecución la clave de desencriptado es distinta de la de encriptado. Dicho de otro modo, puedo encriptar en primera ejecución y desencriptar, pero en la segunda ejecución no desencripta el dato encriptado en la primera ejecución.

Comment: Cierto que podría guardarlo en la misma base de datos, pero, ¿eso no sería como darle la mitad del descifrado a un posible atacante?

Comment: No lo es. Se necesita esta parte para decifrar, pero la razon porque se usa es distinto. Si se transmite un dato cifrado tambien se envía junto con el dato en muchos casos. Lo importante es que no se reusa con la misma clave.

Comment: Usando la base de datos Neodatis como uso, se puede abrir con notepad++ para ver el contenido aunque no a que variable del objeto pertenece. Es por eso que no quiero dejar ninguna pista para su desencriptado. Teniendo el IV y el dato encriptado, pero no la clave de encriptación,¿qué posibilidades de desencriptado​ mediante fuerza bruta existen si usamos un ordenador moderno? ¿Nulas, bajas, medias, altas o pan comido?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55394/discussion-between-stefan-nolde-and-daniel-ruiz).

Comment: @DanielRuiz usa un MD5 de tu palabra clave como clave (tienes que cambiar el método a trabajar con `byte[]` en vez de `String`) y tu puedes tranquilamente guardar el `iv` con tu dato secreto. Un computador como el mio necesitaría en promedio 1+E26 años para adivinar la clave por fuerza bruta "tonta". Obviamente podría tener suerte... ;) Si quieres más explicaciones deberías abrir una nueva pregunta con el código que tienes hasta ahora y te puedo dar mejores explicaciones sobre donde están tus vectores de ataque - no es el algoritmo ;) Suficiente seguro?

Comment: Llegados a este punto tienes razón en que lo mejor será abrir una nueva pregunta detallada. No obstante, tengo entendido que md5 hace años que es fácil de romper y se recomienda el uso de SHA1. ¿Me equivoco?

Comment: No te equivocas, pero la idea es de crear una "contraseña" de tamaño fija binaria desde una contraseña de tamaño variable y la "cifra" en eso es entropía añadida. MD5 tiene 128bit, SHA-1 o SHA-256 tienen más. Es para una pregunta más alla.

Comment: He encontrado un código que incluye AES+SHA1, salt e iv. Me da la impresión que mejora más la seguridad en comparación a lo que tenía. Si quieres dale un vistazo a la pregunta que he abierto en http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55465/error-al-encriptar-exception-in-thread-main-java-security-invalidkeyexception

Comment: Lo ví. En vez de usar MD5 puedes usar SHA-256, partirlo en 2 segmentos y hacer un XOR. Estoy un poco occupado por ahora, más rato te dejo una sugerencia con código y explicación.