# Error al encriptar: Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters

Tags: java, encriptación, sha1

Estoy probando un código que encontré en Github para encriptar datos que me pareció bastante seguro. Lo he modificado un poco por que usaba sun.misc.BASE64Encoder() y sun.misc.BASE64Decoder(), y java 8 marca como que va a desaparecer. El código original está en [Github](https://gist.github.com/scotttam/874426) .
Esa parte la he sustituido por DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary y DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary.

Pues bien, al ejecutar el código me sale el error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1026)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:801)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1249)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1186)
    at utils.Decrypter.encrypt(Decrypter.java:36)
    at utils.Decrypter.main(Decrypter.java:56)
Java Result: 1
```

El código que tengo en es:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import java.security.AlgorithmParameters;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class Decrypter {
    Cipher dcipher;

    byte[] salt = new String("12345678").getBytes();
    int iterationCount = 1024;
    int keyStrength = 256;
    SecretKey key;
    byte[] iv;

    Decrypter(String passPhrase) throws Exception {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount, keyStrength);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        key = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    }

    public String encrypt(String data) throws Exception {
        dcipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        AlgorithmParameters params = dcipher.getParameters();
        iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        byte[] utf8EncryptedData = dcipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
        String base64EncryptedData = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(utf8EncryptedData);

        System.out.println("IV " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(iv));
        System.out.println("Encrypted Data " + base64EncryptedData);
        return base64EncryptedData;
    }

    public String decrypt(String base64EncryptedData) throws Exception {
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] decryptedData = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64EncryptedData);
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(decryptedData);
        return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Decrypter decrypter = new Decrypter("ABCDEFGHIJKL");
        String encrypted = decrypter.encrypt("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
        String decrypted = decrypter.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println(decrypted);
    }
}
```

He intentado encontrar respuesta en preguntas ya formuladas sin resultado alguno, por eso especifico mi caso en busca de ayuda.
Además de este problema, si puede ser, quisiera saber si veis muy seguro el código que quiero utilizar.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner qué codigo realizas en la llamada al método para que te lance el error?

Comment: Está toda la clase ya en la explicación.  
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Decrypter decrypter = new Decrypter("ABCDEFGHIJKL");
        String encrypted = decrypter.encrypt("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
        String decrypted = decrypter.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println(decrypted);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Por defecto Java solo soporta `128-bit` a la hora de encriptar.

Esto equivale a ***16 carácteres***. Por lo que la cadena a encriptar: `"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"` no es válida.

Si vas a encriptar algo que contenga más de 16 carácteres deberás de instalarte la extensión **[Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6481658/1008278)**.

Comment: Justamente eso estaba mirando pero al instalar he ido a la ruta C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\security y he visto que esos dos archivos ya existen por lo que no lo he tocado. Por otro lado he probado a cambiar el int keyStrength = 256; a int keyStrength = 128; y he cambiado la cadena a encriptar por una de 16 caracteres y el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: He sustituido los archivos y ahora funciona. ¿Sería necesario que se copien los dos archivos en cada ordenador donde el programa finalizado se ejecutase?

Comment: Puedes compilar tu programa para que incluya las librerías, y para ejecutarlo no haga falta tener esas librerías en el pc ya que las incluiría tu ejecutable. Aquí tienes la forma en Eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11033670/5014993

Comment: Sinceramente no tengo ni idea de como hacer eso último. ¿Debería abrir una nueva pregunta o es viable como comentario?

Comment: @DanielRuiz los jars siempre existen, pero son distintos si quieres trabajar con criptografía fuerza ilimitada. Dependiente que métodos de padding y algoritmos usas no puedes simplemente cambiar los tamaños de las claves. El método tiene que tener sentido.

Comment: @cnbandicoot la limitación es por la clave que esta limitado a 128bit en AES, por los datos cifrados. La frase arriba se puede encriptar perfectamente, y frases muchos más largo, para eso AES usa una cadena de cifra de bloques.Lo que no se puede hacer sin las políticas alternativas es encriptar con claves más largos.

Answer (score 1):

Java soporta muchos algoritmos de encriptación seguros, pero algunos de ellos son débiles para ser utilizados en aplicaciones que requieren mucha seguridad. Por ejemplo, el algoritmo de encriptación [Data Encryption Standard (DES)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) es considerado altamente inseguro; Los mensajes cifrados con DES han sido descifrados por la fuerza bruta en un solo día por máquinas como el [Deep Crack de la Electronic Frontier Foundation (EFF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFF_DES_cracker).

Un algoritmo de cifrado más seguro es [AES - Advanced Encryption Standard](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), que es un algoritmo de cifrado simétrico. El cifrado de AES es utilizado por los EEUU para asegurar el material sensible pero no clasificado, así que podemos decir que es bastante seguro.

Aquí tienes un código de ejemplo de cómo usar AES:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AES {

    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key;

    public static void setKey(String myKey) 
    {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); 
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret) 
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error de encriptación: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) 
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error de descifrado: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

**Código de prueba**

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final String secretKey = "estaesunaclavesecreta";

    String originalString = "encriptaesto/decripta/esto";
    String encryptedString = AES.encrypt(originalString, secretKey) ;
    String decryptedString = AES.decrypt(encryptedString, secretKey) ;

    System.out.println(originalString);
    System.out.println(encryptedString);
    System.out.println(decryptedString);
}
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco, el código que estoy utilizando ahora utiliza AES+SHA1 y eso que llaman salt que dicen que es para evitar el uso de diccionarios. El que me muestras se parece a uno que no usaba SHA1, si no iv.

Comment: Si te fijas en el código, usa sha-1: `sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");`  y si prefieres puedes probar también con MD5 o con  SHA256 usando la misma clase `MessageDigest`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html  Ver también: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest

Comment: Partiendo de la base de que tengo pocos conocimientos de encriptacion, ¿sería más recomendable tu código o el que estoy usando actualmente?

Comment: @DanielRuiz Al leer: _El código que tengo en es_ interpreté que estabas usando Des... pero viendo el código en realidad estás usando AES, o sea que ambos son seguros, la diferencia es entre ECB / CBC . Un muchos foros se dice que CBC es más seguro pero que a veces da problemas, en otros dicen que depende. En definitiva, ambos son seguros.

Comment: Creo que al final voy a usar tu código con alguna modificación. Aunque el otro tiene la ventaja de usar el iv y salt, a la hora de desencriptar es una barbaridad que no compensa, ya que necesitaría conservar el iv de cada variable de cada objeto en la base de datos. Puesto que hoy día se considera seguro un cifrado AES + SHA1 de 128 bits, lo subo a 256 (32bytes), encripto también la clave en si y doy por zanjada la parte de encriptación.

Comment: @A.Cedano se considera de no usar ECB para cifrar más que un bloque, menos aun con el mismo vector. CBC evita la vulnerabilidad por una cadena de encriptación. Sin embargo para evitar ataques inyectando datos conocidos con vectores previsibles, CBC debería usar iv's aleatorios.

Comment: @DanielRuiz porque no simplemente guardas el IV como hex con el cifrado en base64 concatenado en un campo de texto? Hacía del ECB, revisa la especificación como funciona y para que se usa, y luego revisa si eso es tu caso de uso. Solamente tienes datos extremadamente cortos? Tampoco recomiendo de usar el mismo hash tal cual como clave y al mismo tiempo como IV. Es tentador, pero no exactamente aleatorio, y todo que no tiene suficente entropía en la criptografía es más arriesgado.

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo @Stefan Nolde. ¿Quieres decir que pase el IV a hexadecimal, lo cifre con base 64 y lo que sale lo guarde en la base de datos para luego realizar el proceso inverso al necesitarlo como parte del proceso de desencriptado? ¿No sería posible que alguien realizando el mismo proceso de desencriptado llegase a conocer el IV? Te pido disculpas pues soy nuevo en criptografía y estoy intentando asimilar muchos conceptos a la vez.

Comment: @DanielRuiz revisa `buildEntry()` y `parseEntry()` en el código que te dejé (la segunda clase). Es un ejemplo como guardar IV y datos en un solo campo de texto, y como separarlo de nuevo. 32 caracteres IV en hex + el dato en base64. Manejas el concepto de un DAO?

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres hacer funcionar encriptación de 256bit con AES, tienes que instalar las políticas ilimitadas de oracle que lo permiten. Este nivel de criptografía no esta permitido para organismos privados en todos los países del mundo.

en la pagina de [Oracle](http://oracle.com/), busca por "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files" para la versión de java que usas.
Luego copias `local_policy.jar` y `US_export_policy.jar` a la subcarpeta `lib/security/` de tu `JDK`. El archivo contiene un `README.txt` con estos instrucciones.

TLDR; fin.

Daniel, más que nada trabajando con seguridad es preferible de entender lo que uno hace ne vez de hacer funcionar lo que uno encuentra en el internet. Tomando en cuenta las preguntas que tuviste en tu [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54098), te dejo un ejemplo comprobado como guardar datos cifrados en una base de datos, y te aclaro las dudas que te quedaban. El código usa exclusivamente la biblioteca de sistema sin dependencias de terceros.

Para empezar, la clase para la cifra, en que puedes eligir si quieres usar `MD5` o `SHA-256` usando `xor` para reducir el hash a 128bit. Me preguntaste si `MD5` no sería inseguro, porque ya hay pruebas que se puede romper la cifra. En este caso eso no importa mucho, porque el *hash* solamente se usa para generar una clave binario de tamaño definido desde una clave del usuario. Más abajo te explico más detallado por qué la vulnerabilidad de MD5 en este caso no tiene mucho impacto. si eso no te convence, puedes usar el modo "paranoico", usando dos partes de un *hash* `SHA-256` combinado por `xor`.

La clase `CryptoStore` provee un "value object" `Secret` que contiene el vector de inicialisación y el dato, y como interfaz estático interno `CryptoStoreDAO`, que puedes implementar con tu *DAO* para acceder a tu base de datos. El interfaz define dos métodos:

- `saveSecret(T referencia, Secret secreto)` - para guardar el secreto cifrado en la base de tatos según referencia, y
- `loadSecret(T referencia)` - para recuperar el secreto de la base de datos según referencia.

La clase `CryptoStore` tiene dos métodos que acceden directamente los métodos de la interfaz para persistir y recuperar los datos usando el *DAO*.

```
package com.snolde.crypto;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

/**
 * @author snolde 2017
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public class CryptoStore<T> {

    public static interface CryptoStoreDAO<T>{
        public Secret loadSecret(T reference);
        public boolean saveSecret(T reference, Secret secret);
    }
    public static class Secret{
        public final String data;
        public final byte[] iv;
        public Secret (String data, byte[] iv){
            this.data=data;
            this.iv=iv;
        }
    }
    public static final String MD5="MD5";
    public static final String SHA="SHA-256";
    public static final String ENCODING="UTF-8";
    private static final SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();

    private MessageDigest md;

    private byte[] iv = new byte[16];

    /**
     * paranoid uses SHA with XOR
     * @param paranoid
     */
    public CryptoStore(boolean paranoid){
            try {
                if (paranoid) md=MessageDigest.getInstance(SHA);
                        else md=MessageDigest.getInstance(MD5);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {}
    }

    public String decode(String pass, Secret secret){
        iv = secret.iv;
        try {
            byte[] key = key2Hash(pass);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks, ips);

            return new String 
                    (cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(secret.data)),"UTF-8");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // won't happen, if so...
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // won't happen, if so...
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // won't happen, if so...
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            // won't happen, if so...
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            // won't happen, if so...
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // won't happen, if so...
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            // this can happen if you try to decode with the wrong key 
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Secret encode(String pass, String data){
        sr.nextBytes(iv);
            try {
                byte[] key = key2Hash(pass);
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
                IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
                SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks, ips);

                byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
                return new Secret(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encrypted),iv);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // won't happen, if so...
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                // won't happen, if so...
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                // won't happen, if so...
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
                // won't happen, if so...
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
                // won't happen, if so...
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
                // won't happen, if so...
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
    }

    /**
     * @return if paranoid SHA-256 XOR is used
     */
    public boolean isParanoid(){
        return md.getAlgorithm().startsWith(SHA);
    }

    private byte[] key2Hash(String key){
        try {
            byte[] hash = md.digest(key.getBytes(ENCODING));
            if (!isParanoid()) return hash;
            // we are paranoid, lets XOR the SHA-256
            byte[] pHash = new byte[16];
            for (int i = 0;i<16;i++){
                pHash[i] = (byte) (hash[i]^hash[i+16]);
            }
            return pHash;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // Not going to happen. Never say never, throw RTE.
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    public void storeSecret(CryptoStoreDAO<T> dao, T reference,  String pass, String data){
        dao.saveSecret(reference, encode(pass,data));
    }
    public String unstoreSecret(CryptoStoreDAO<T> dao, T reference, String pass){
        Secret secret = dao.loadSecret(reference);
        return decode(pass, secret);
    }
}
```

Un ejemplo de uso para `CryptoStore` tienes aqui, en forma de una simulación de una base de datos usando un `HashMap` como tabla:

```
package classes;

import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import com.snolde.crypto.CryptoStore;
import com.snolde.crypto.CryptoStore.*;

/**
 * @author snolde
 *
 */
public class CryptoStoreEjemplo implements CryptoStoreDAO<Integer> {

    HashMap<Integer, String> table = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CryptoStoreEjemplo dao = new CryptoStoreEjemplo();
        CryptoStore<Integer> csMd5 = new CryptoStore<Integer>(false);
        csMd5.storeSecret(dao, 0, "foo", "mi foo es mejor que tu foo");
        csMd5.storeSecret(dao, 1, "bar", "Vamos a ir a un bar!");
        csMd5.storeSecret(dao, 2, "foobar", "Me encontré con un foo en un bar.");
        System.out.println(csMd5.unstoreSecret(dao, 0, "foo"));
        System.out.println(csMd5.unstoreSecret(dao, 1, "bar"));
        System.out.println(csMd5.unstoreSecret(dao, 2, "foobar"));
        System.out.println(csMd5.unstoreSecret(dao, 0, "nonfoo"));
        System.out.println(csMd5.unstoreSecret(dao, 1, "ningunbar"));
        System.out.println(csMd5.unstoreSecret(dao, 2, "foobarquizás"));
        CryptoStore<Integer> csSHA = new CryptoStore<Integer>(true);
        csSHA.storeSecret(dao, 3, "foo", "SHA foo es más seguro");
        csSHA.storeSecret(dao, 4, "bar", "Nadie puede roBAR un SHA");
        csSHA.storeSecret(dao, 5, "foobar", "Hay que comproBAR el foo!");
        System.out.println(csSHA.unstoreSecret(dao, 3, "foo"));
        System.out.println(csSHA.unstoreSecret(dao, 4, "bar"));
        System.out.println(csSHA.unstoreSecret(dao, 5, "foobar"));
        System.out.println(csSHA.unstoreSecret(dao, 3, "nonfoo"));
        System.out.println(csSHA.unstoreSecret(dao, 4, "ningunbar"));
        System.out.println(csSHA.unstoreSecret(dao, 5, "foobarquizás"));
    }


    private static String buildEntry(Secret secret){
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(secret.iv) + secret.data;
    }

    private static Secret parseEntry(String entry){
        byte[] iv = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(entry.substring(0, 32));
        String data = entry.substring(32);
        return new Secret(data,iv);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.snolde.crypto.CryptoStore.CryptoStoreDAO#loadSecret(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public Secret loadSecret(Integer reference) {
        Secret secret = parseEntry(table.get(reference));
        return secret;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.snolde.crypto.CryptoStore.CryptoStoreDAO#saveSecret(java.lang.Object, com.snolde.crypto.CryptoStore.Secret)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean saveSecret(Integer reference, Secret secret) {
        String entry = buildEntry(secret);
        table.put(reference, entry);
        return true;
    }

}
```

La salida cuando corres el `main`:

```
mi foo es mejor que tu foo
Vamos a ir a un bar!
Me encontré con un foo en un bar.
null
null
null
SHA foo es más seguro
Nadie puede roBAR un SHA
Hay que comproBAR el foo!
null
null
null
```

***Ahora las explicaciónes sobre el por qué***

**1) ¿Por qué debería usar un valor criptográficamente aleatorio como vector de inicialisación?**

El vector de inicialisación sirve como paquete inicial para los ciclos de cifración. Si permites que el mismo vector se usa para datos distintos, puedes abrir vulnerabilidades en tu cifra. Deberías ver el *iv* como un dato desechable, que presenta un riesgo incremental lo más que lo reutilizas.

**2) ¿No debería usar SHA en vez de MD5 por los vulnerabilidades de MD5?**

Eso sería un punto válido si se usaría el *hash* para validar accesos, pero en este caso no es así. Se usa un hash por la única razón de generar una clave binaria de 128bit porque el algoritmo AES del ejemplo lo necesita en exactamente este tamaño. Para eso ni siquiera se necesitaría un *hash* criptográfico, aun que si existe un impacto menor dependiente de la probabilidad de colisiones (dos o más valores distintos apuntan al mismo hash) del algoritmo del *hash*. De esta probabilidad de colisiones se podría aprovechar un atacante en el caso que descubriera un *hash* y buscaría una clave para el mismo. En Nuestro caso aun el *hash* nunca se guarda, así queda invisible para atacantes. Mucho más importante es de no reutilizar el vector de inicialisación.

**3) ¿No sería más seguro de esconder un `iv` fijo en mi código que guardar uno aleatorio con mi datos?**

Definitivamente **NO**. Decompilar bytecode es un problema de un plátano. La importancia del `iv` (disculpa si me repito mucho en eso) **no** es que sería secreto, es que en el caso ideal no se repite con datos distintos y la misma clave. Se asume que `AES` correctamente aplicado solamente puede ser quebrado por fuerza bruta, eso significa que hay que comprobar entre 2^128 posibles claves. En un test conociendo el `iv` estimé que en mi maquina de desarrollo necesitaría 1.0E+26 años para comprobar **la mitad** de las posibilidades. La población mundial actualmente son 7.5E+09 personas, asumiendo que podría construir una red de bots usando este cantidad de computadores, me quedarían 1.4E+16 años para la tarea.

**4) ¿No sería mejor de usar criptografía más fuerte, clave de 512bit o algo?**

Mientras trabajas con contraseñas, más que nada contraseñas inventadas por humanos, el tamaño de la clave **no es tu punto debil**. Es el usuario. Mucho más fácil que atacar tu almacenamiento cifrado es atacar la contraseña. Fuerza bruta asumiendo un ms por iteración (Netbook):

- 4-6 caracteres [a-z]: ~90 horas
- 6-8 caracteres [a-zA-Z]: ~1700 años
- 6-10 caracteres [a-zA-Z0-9]: 21 mio años

Asumiendo contraseñas de puras palabras existentes en minúsculas sería una tarea para... 80 segundos en la misma maquina.

Y ni hablemos de fechas de nacimiento, nombres de hijos, "amorcito1985" etc.

En Resumen: Antes de atacar un secreto protegido por AES/CBC 128bit, prefiero contratar una señorita del escort que involucra mi usuario en cuestión en una relación romántica fingida y luego analizo las informaciones obtenidos para ver si se pueden deducir contraseñas posibles desde la personalidad y detalles personales de la persona en cuestión. Me sale mucho más barato y probablemente más rápido.

Comment: Es un código más complejo al cual no estoy acostumbrado. Lo leeré con calma y lo analizaré para entenderlo.

Comment: El código en el fondo es más simple que el tuyo. Tonde te quedan dudas? También me puedes preguntar [en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53063)

Comment: Muy bien. Creo que ya entiendo el código. A parte de encriptar y desencriptar, guarda una concatenación del iv y el dato usando  DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(). Dicha combinación la desglosa antes de desencriptar y usa el iv y el dato encriptado en dicha acción. A partir de ahí podría darle más seguridad a dicha concatenación, por ejemplo, no se... ¿pasándolo a hexadecimal? Ya se que no haría nada, pero conseguiría marear un poco a un posible atacante que no tiene por que saber que está en hexadecimal. ¿Qué me sugieres? En cuanto al DAO, no lo usé nunca, aunque ahora me he informado.

Comment: Si solamente tienes atacantes que puedes marear simplemente cambiando la representación de tus datos, tomate una cerveza y relajate - estas seguro ;) La representación de hex solamente eligí porque es seguro de guardar en un TEXT de una BD y porque es facil de calcular su tamaño (2*bytes). Lo importante del nivel de tu seguridad es: Siempre recalcular un IV aleatorio nuevo y exigir una buena complejidad de tus contraseñas (largo 8+, mayúscula/minúscula/numero/especiál)

Comment: Yo es que soy más de café XD XD. A ver, lo que quería decir realmente es que si que estoy de acuerdo en usar un iv distinto cada vez, pero además de eso hacer algo como en vez de concatenar los datos con DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(secret.iv) + secret.data hacerlo en base64 con la librería de apache commons.

Comment: DatatypeConverter maneja hex, base64 y más, no hay necesidad para bibliotecas externas, Yo solamente usaría apache commons en un caso así si ya lo uso en general por otras razones. Puedes cambiar la representación a tu gusto, siempre mientras puedes separar los dos en una forma estable.

Comment: Para hacerme una idea: Si un atacante llegase a obtener los iv por que resulta que ha descubierto que está concatenado con el dato encriptado, en base a estos dos elementos, ¿qué posibilidades habría de que consiguiese saber la contraseña de encriptado y llegar a descifrar algún dato? Pongamos que se usa una contraseña segura.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55510/discussion-between-stefan-nolde-and-daniel-ruiz).

Answer (score 0):

te dejo un código que uso habitualmente (adaptado a tu ejemplo) que a mi siempre me ha funcionado correctamente.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Decrypter {

    private String secretKey;

    public Decrypter(String secretKey) {
        this.secretKey = secretKey;
    }

    public String encrypt(String data) throws Exception {
        String base64EncryptedString = "";

        try {

            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(secretKey.getBytes("utf-8"));
            byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);

            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

            byte[] plainTextBytes = data.getBytes("utf-8");
            byte[] buf = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
            byte[] base64Bytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(buf);
            base64EncryptedString = new String(base64Bytes);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return base64EncryptedString;
    }

    public String decrypt(String base64EncryptedData) throws Exception {
        String base64EncryptedString = "";

        try {
            byte[] message = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64EncryptedData.getBytes("utf-8"));
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(secretKey.getBytes("utf-8"));
            byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");

            Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
            decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

            byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);

            base64EncryptedString = new String(plainText, "UTF-8");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return base64EncryptedString;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Decrypter decrypter = new Decrypter("mipasswordimpenetrable");
        String encrypted = decrypter.encrypt("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
        String decrypted = decrypter.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println(decrypted);
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: No soy experto, pero ¿ese código encripta en MD5? Según tengo entendido MD5 fue considerado no seguro en 2004.

Comment: No he tenido problemas hasta el momento. Si la seguridad en tu aplicación no es crítica te puede servir.

Comment: En realidad busco la encriptacion más segura que exista. Los datos que se van a encriptar son importantes.