# Proteger archivos importantes de programa Java

Tags: java, archivo, seguridad

Saludos..

Bueno esta es mi dura.. estoy desarrollando un proyecto en Java, aunque esto aplicara para cualquier lenguaje, el punto es que, cuando distribuya mi sistema el cual trabaja con  archivos que no mando a la base de datos, sino que creo .txt y carpetas para porque no ameritan ser guardados un una base de datos pero aun asi necesitan seguridad igual, me gustaria saber como proteger esos archivos de que manera puedo mantener al usuario al margen con esos archivos si es muy curios@.

Quisiera saber que metodos hay para la proteccion de archivos asi sin que afecte el funcionamiente del sistema como tal.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Jamás podrás evitar que un usuario curioso de con esos archivos. Por sentido común, hay que ponerlos en un lugar inaccesible para el 90% de usuarios; por ejemplo en ~/.tuapp o en C:\users  de Windows, si son ocultos mejor. En caso la cosa sea extrema guarda sus configuraciones en la nube, así las mantienes seguras.

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué tal si encriptas la información y aunque el usuario de con ellos, esta sea inaccesible para él?
En este enlace tienes información de como hacerlo: [Encriptado y desencriptado AES+SHA1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/55497/32268)

Comment: Voy a probar eso, la verdad quería encriptar mis archivos desde un principio. voy a probar esto y luego avisare que tal. muchas gracias.