# ¿Por qué al intentar poner una clave de 24 o 32 caracteres no cifra mi programa AES?

Tags: java, criptografía, cifrado

```
package aesprueba;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;



public class AESprueba {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
 * @throws java.security.NoSuchProviderException
 * @throws javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException
 * @throws java.security.InvalidKeyException
 * @throws javax.crypto.ShortBufferException
 * @throws javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
 * @throws javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, ShortBufferException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    byte [] mensaje = "Hola amigos mios".getBytes();
    byte [] clave = "asdfghjkasdfghjk".getBytes();
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(clave, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte [] ciphertext = new byte [cipher.getOutputSize(mensaje.length)];


        int ciphertextLength = cipher.update(mensaje, 0, mensaje.length, ciphertext, 0);
        ciphertextLength += cipher.doFinal(ciphertext, ciphertextLength);

        StringBuffer hexCipher = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0; i<ciphertext.length; i++)
            hexCipher.append(Integer.toString((ciphertext[i]&0xff)+0x100,16).substring(1));

        System.out.println("Cipher: " + hexCipher);


}
```

}

Me aparece este error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
>       at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1026)
>       at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:801)
>       at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
>       at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1249)
>       at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1186)
>       at aesprueba.AESprueba.main(AESprueba.java:36)

---

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Java usas? Si hace tiempo que no actualizas puede ser que necesites instalar el [JCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Cryptography_Extension) para que te funcione

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/55478/22851

Comment: @PabloLozano Acabode instalar el JCE pero aun así me sigue marcando el mismo error...

Answer (score 0):

No es el JCE, eso viene de caja con el JDK desde Java-5

Históricamente las versiones del JDK venían con la criptografía limitada por las leyes de exportación de armamento. De traca, pero así es.

En determinadas versiones del JDK era necesario sustituir los ficheros de políticas de seguridad en el JRE por los que proporciona Oracle (que se supone que no podrías descargar desde peligrosos y malvados países).

En realidad es algo más complejo y es algo diferente según la versión:

**JDKs anteriores a JDK8-u162**

Casi seguro que es tu caso.

Para los JDKs anteriores a JDK8-u162 necesitas reemplazar los "jar" del JCE con los citados JAR de políticas sin restricción.

- **JAVA 7** http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

  **JAVA 8** http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Descargalos y sustituye el contenido en `<java-home>/lib/security` de los ficheros que acabas de descargar: *local_policy.jar* y *US_export_policy.jar*

**JDK8 u151**

Aquí han cambiado, no es necesario descargarlos porque ya vienen, pero debes hacer este cambio

```
Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");
```

en el JRE del JDK

**JDK8 u162 y en JDK9**

Desde Java-8-u162 la política criptográfica sin restricciones ya viene de caja -- esto es una traducción rara de *"out-of-the-box"* :)